# Does anybody know what kind of snake is this?

Tags: species-identification, snake

FYI the snake is dead and currently in my freezer, I got it from a guy and forgot to ask what kind it is. [image]

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add the location where this snake was found?

Comment: I am from Czech Republic, but the snake is definitely exotic, it was a pet.

Comment: Is it pictured with the head upside down?

Comment: I need a better picture. thaw it, put it in some kind of position so that I can see the back,and give me a length measurement.At least.

Answer (score 2):

This is Orthriophis taeniurus ridleyi, a synonym is Elaphe taeniura. It has a few common names,some are  Ridley's beauty snake,Cave beauty and Cave racer.

https://www.biolib.cz/en/taxon/id310150/

https://www.naturepl.com/search?s=orthriophis+taeniurus+ridleyi2581

https://www.zootierliste.de/en/?klasse=3&ordnung=305&familie=30513&art=21102660

https://www.thainationalparks.com/species/orthriophis-taeniurus

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beauty_rat_snake

https://www.reptarium.cz/en/taxonomy/Orthriophis-taeniurus/2581